# Subclipse wants to commit an folder conaining an svn:ignore file

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, svnignore

I have a project with a subfolder Resources. In this folder there is a file I added to SVN:ignore.

Now there aren't any other changes compared with the latest respository revision. But in eclipse's synchronzite view, this folder is still beeing displayed. No other files are displayed under it, because nothing changed.

- Why is this folder beeing displayed in the synchronize view?
- Is it because SVN metadata changed?
- Do I have to commit the metadata into the repository?
- Is there a way, to get this folder out of the synchronize view, without commiting metadata?

I don't want to commit those SVN:ignore metadata, because its user specific. I don't want to ignore the folder's contents, because there are regular files which has to be version controlled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must commit svn:ignore when it should be work. There is no other way I think. Because all project metadata are under version control!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because SVN metadata changed?

Yes, you modified the `svn:ignore` property of the `Resources` folder.

> Do I have to commit the metadata into the repository?

Yes, `svn:ignore` properties are stored in the repository. They are shared between all SVN users.

> Is there a way, to get this folder out of the synchronize view, without commiting metadata? I don't want to commit those SVN:ignore metadata, because its user specific.

Yes. You can use `global-ignores` in your SVN configuration file, instead of the `svn:ignore` property. From the section [Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) in the SVN book:

> global-ignores
>
> When running the `svn status` command, Subversion lists unversioned files and directories along with the versioned ones, annotating them with a `?` character (see the section called “See an overview of your changes”). Sometimes it can be annoying to see uninteresting, unversioned items—for example, object files that result from a program's compilation—in this display. The global-ignores option is a list of whitespace-delimited globs that describe the names of files and directories that Subversion should not display unless they are versioned. The default value is `*.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is trying to add the .ignore file itself? (It might have created that file to list ignored files.) Check for any other hidden files too.

if you want, you can add the whole folder to the ignore list

**EDIT**

Svn does not create a ignore file list, but maybe it is committing the parent folder or there is some hidden file inside that folder

Comment: The .svn folder containing the svn metadata is the only thing which is hidden there. The file .svn/dir-props contains the information for ignoring the file. Maybe there is more metadata somewhere else, but I don't think so.

Comment: so, add .svn folder to the ignore list. I'm not sure if svn does it automatically. Anyway, you might want to commit the hidden files list because probably everyone else will have the same hidden files/folders.